# IllegalMonitorStateException thrown in synchronized(lock){lock.notify();} ... why?

Tags: android, exception, locking, notify

I'm debugging an Android service written by one of our previous developers, and he's used a `Boolean` in the following way:

```
public static class DownloadQueue extends LinkedHashMap  
{
    // ...
    private Boolean lock = new Boolean(false);
    // ...

    //typical notify use
    synchronized public Object addToHead(Object key, Object value)
    {
        // ...
        synchronized (lock) 
        {
            //IllegalMonitorStateException FROM HERE
            lock.notify();
        }
        // ...
        return null;
    }

    //queue machinery
    public DownloadRecord getFirst()
    {
        // we block because queue is empty
        if(this.size() == 0 || (MyApp.isInternetConnectionAvailable() == false))
        {
            try 
            {   
                lock = true;
                synchronized (lock) 
                {
                    lock.wait(30000);
                }
                lock = false;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {}
        //continue operating the queue
        // ...
        return value;
    }
}
```

The documentation I've found on `IllegalMonitorStateException` suggests it's caused by not calling `notify()` from a `synchronized` block; however, that is clearly not the case here.  I did wonder if the scope of `lock` might be a problem, or whether the unsynchronized assignments could be.  All the references to `lock` are of the form above, with just the one `wait(long)` in the queue function.

One final, possibly useful detail: this is occurring because, although our device has network, our CMS is down.  We're taking the opportunity to test the app in this condition.  I suspect the queue might be operating at breakneck speed because failed downloads are getting requeued, so if a race condition is a possible cause of this fault, then it may be the cause here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are reassigning the value of the `lock` member variable in your `getFirst` method.

Boolean is an immutable type, so when you reassign its value you are creating a new Object.

That means you are not guaranteed to be notifying the same object that you synchronized on (if reassignment happens in between).

It is a good practice to declare lock variables as `final` to avoid this kind of programming error.

Comment: Thank you!  That looks like the solution to me :)

Comment: I've additionally determined that the value of `lock` is never read, so I removed the writes.

Answer (score 4):

Your synchonization on the lock variable isn't working because you keep reassigning it: when you do this  `lock = true;` or  `lock = false;` you are changing the object to which "lock" refers. So when you obtain a lock on it in your `addToHead` method and then another thread calls getFirst, the reference of lock is changed underneath it so it points to something else by time you call notify.